# Trying to automate writing csv to latex template with python

Tags: python, csv, latex, pdflatex

Here is my CSV file:

```
Simon,/home/user/Desktop/simon.jpeg
```

Here is my Python code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import csv
import subprocess
LatexContent = '''\\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn, letterpaper]{report}
                        \\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
                        \\usepackage{graphicx}
                        \\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\\sfdefault} 
                            \\begin{document}
                            Run Satus: \\textsc{%(sampleid)s}
                            %(sampleid)s
                            \\includegraphics[width=20cm]{%(coveragegraph)s}
                                \\end{document}'''


###== Look at the database ==##
# open the database into python
my_db_file = open('automate.testing.csv', 'r') 

# read the database
my_db = csv.reader(my_db_file, delimiter=',',skipinitialspace=True)

###== TeX files processing and generating ==###
#skip the header of the database
next(my_db)

#then for each row of the database
for row in my_db :
    ## Assign the items of the row to the variables that will fill up the 
    ##    blanks of the LaTeX code
    sampleid = str(row[0])            #caution, first item of a row = index '0'
    coveragegraph = str(row[1])


        #define the TeX file name
    TexFileName = sampleid + '.tex'

    ## create a new LaTeX file with the blanks filled
        #create a new file
    TexFile = open(TexFileName,'w')

        #fill the blanks with the previously read informations
    TexFile.write(LatexContent %{"sampleid" : sampleid, "coveragegraph" : coveragegraph})

        #close the file
    TexFile.close()

    ## compile the file you've just created with LaTeX        
    subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex',TexFileName],shell=False)      

    ##repeat for each row

#close the database file
my_db_file.close()
```

I want to be able to execute the Python script, have it read in the CSV file, and put the values into the `latexcontent` section which will then be executed with `pdflatex`.

When I hit enter it appears to execute fine, no error codes. But there is no `.tex` file created in the directory.

What changes should I make to the Python to make it work, I know I am close...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the first issue I see is that you only have one row in your `.csv` file, but you use the `next()` function to "skip the header". There is no header in the `.csv` you gave, so you're skipping over the only data you have.

Then when you get to the `for row in my_db :` line, there aren't any rows to iterate over, so the code never actually makes it to any write statements.

Try deleting the `next()` in your code or modifying your `.csv` to include headers, then post an update with the new output.

Comment: Hi, I got rid of the next(), and had to remove the \\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\\sfdefault} in the Latex bit, was throwing an error. It has made the PDF, Thankyou!